# Prior art request for issued patent U.S.7818924 B2

Tags: prior-art-request, post-grant, us7818924, b2

Title: Foam insulation/shading system for transparent structures. 
Assignee name:  Sunarc Of Canada Inc.

HELP SAVE INDUSTRY THREATENED BY OVERLY BROAD US 7818924 B2 patent.
Sunrac of Canada patent is:
A periodically shieldable solar structure (10) comprises a cavity formed between a pair of light transmitting members (12). A foam insulation/shading system (14) is provided for periodically filling the cavity with degradable foam. The foam insulation/shading system (14) comprises a series of foam generators (28) mounted within the cavity and distributed to provide multiple foam generating points. The foam generators (28) are operatively coupled to a source of pressurized air and a source of foaming solution.

10 minutes of your time can help narrow this US patent or have it be declared invalid.
FIG. 1 is a schematic perspective vieW of a loW pressure
foam generation system used in the insulation and/ or shading
of a greenhouse in accordance With one embodiment of the
present invention;

Have you seen anything that was published before: Mar. 9, 2004.

This invention relates to a structure (typically a green house) that has as walls and roof an outside membrane and an inside membrane. The membranes are transparent and allows light to pass through. The outside and inside membranes form cavities or compartments into which foam is deposited to block the sunlight. After a while the foam turns into water and is replaced by new foam. This way the light that penetrates the structure can be controlled.

If you've ever seen anything like this before, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question -- one piece of prior art per answer. We welcome multiple answers from a single individual.

TITLE: FOAM INSULATION/SHADING SYSTEM FOR TRANSPARENT STRUCTURES

Summary:

Foam insulation/Shading System is provided for the cavity With degradable foam. The foam insulation/shading system (14) comprises a series of foam generators (28) mounted Within the cavity and distributed there along to provide multiple foam generating points The foam generators (28) are operatively coupled to a source of pressurized air and a source of foaming solution.

Publication Number:Oct. 26, 2010

Claim 1:
A periodically shieldable solar structure comprising at least one cavity formed between a pair of light transmitting members, 
and a foam insulation/shading system for periodically filling said at least one cavity with degradable foam, 
said foam insulation/shading system comprising an air supply pipe connected to a source of low-pressure air and extending along said at least one cavity, 
a foaming solution supply pipe connected to a source of foaming solution and extending along said at least one cavity, 
and a series of axially spaced-apart foam generators mounted within said at least one cavity and distributed therealong to provide multiple discrete points of mixture for the air and foaming solution as well as multiple foam outlet points within each single one of said at least one cavity, the foam generators being located in an upper end portion of the at least one cavity, 
the low pressure air and the foaming solution being separately supplied to said foam generators via said air supply pipe and said foaming solution supply pipe to locally produce the foam at each of said axially spaced-apart foam generators, each of the foam generators having a body defining a chamber, 
the chamber having an outlet provided with a screen, each foam generator further having an air inlet configured to provide for a flow of low-pressure air from the air supply pipe to the chamber and at least one nozzle connected to the foaming solution pipe for directly spraying the foaming solution onto an inner face of the screen such that foam is generated by the low-pressure air released through the screen, the axis of the at least one nozzle intersecting the screen.

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already.

What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).

Google patent link: http://www.google.com/patents/US7818924

USPTO link: http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=7818924.PN.&OS=PN/7818924&RS=PN/7818924